# Bind function to class attribute in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I this below code I am not understanding how function "hi", bind to class attribute "say_hi". Can someone make me understand in lucid way. I googled it but explanation is too technical.

```
def hi(obj):
        print("Hi, I am " + obj.name)

class Robot:
    say_hi = hi


x = Robot()
x.name = "Marvin"
Robot.say_hi(x)
```

I am learning Python3 using this link.
https://www.python-course.eu/python3_object_oriented_programming.php

Comment: You can even do `x.say_hi()` O.o

Comment: What do you mean "how"? `say_hi = hi`

Comment: @DeepSpace, I am not getting how above code is working, specially last line Robot.say_hi(x)

Comment: @TARUNPUNETHA Then please read a Python tutorial. SO is *not* a tutorial site. `Robot.say_hi(x)` is a standard method call.

Comment: @DeepSpace it's not a method call at all, it's a function call (thus the (x) )

Answer (score 0):

In Python, functions are also objects and can be assigned to variables. So

```
say_hi = hi
```

enables you to call `say_hi(x)` or `hi(x)` and both will call the same function.

In your code, you've simply assigned the function itself to class attribute `say_hi`, thus, calling `say_hi` is the same as calling `hi`.